# What are services in gitlab pipeline job?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab's pipeline for CI and CD to build images for my projects.
In every job there are configurations to be set like `image` and `stage` but I can't wrap my head around what `services` are. Can someone explain its functionality? Thanks
Here's a code snippet I use that I found

```
build-run:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/my-project:$CI_COMMIT_SHA" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/my-project:$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
  cache:
    untracked: true
  environment: build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation says](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service):

> The `services` keyword defines just another Docker image that is run during your job and is linked to the Docker image that the `image` keyword defines. This allows you to access the service image during build time.